# Запись в две связанные таблицы

Tags: room

Есть объект (smartphone). Он имеет несколько параметров, которые характеризуются двумя таблицами

1. phones с полями: id, Название, Страна
2. parameters с полями: id, id_smartphone, характеристика 1...характеристика n

Т.е. таблица parameters связана с phones по полю id_smartphone. Пользователь в приложении будет добавлять новые смартфоны в БД и сохранять (т.е. записывать в две таблицы данные).

Хотел бы узнать как лучше реализовать связку этих двух таблиц. Поле id таблицы phones сделать автоинкрементируемым или связать их как-то по другому ключу?

Почему спрашиваю? Потому что когда я буду сохранять в БД запись в первую таблицу (phones) записи будет дан некий id, а когда будут записывать данные в таблицу parameters я не смогу связать эти две таблицы. Или можно как-то все-таки их связать?

Comment: *Поле id таблицы phones сделать автоинкрементируемым* Да.

Comment: А как тогда сделать потом связку записи из таблицы phones с данными, которые буду записывать в parameters?

Comment: SELECT * FROM phones AS p LEFT JOIN parameters AS par ON p.id = par.id_smartphone

Comment: *как тогда сделать потом связку записи из таблицы phones с данными, которые буду записывать в parameters?* Связь организуется ДО занесения данных - на этапе создания таблиц. А при записи данных просто следите, чтобы в таблицу параметров в поле связи вставлялось правильное значение id_smartphone. RTFM [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html), [last_insert_rowid()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid).

Comment: Я понял что нужно следить чтобы в id_smartphone занеслось правильное значение. Не знаю как следить. Ведь при добавлении записи в phones я не записываю туда id, а он присваивается автоматом

Comment: Т.е. метод last_insert_rowid() возвращает id последней вставленной записи в таблицу phones?